# Magerun not recognized on command line

Tags: cli, magerun

I am unable to run magerun from the CLI on one of my Commerce cloud sites. How do I fix?

here is the error:

```
var/magerun db:dump --compression="gzip" ./var/mg_integration_before_sync.sql.gz 
PHP Warning: stream_resolve_include_path(): Unable to find the wrapper "phar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 429 
PHP Stack trace: 
PHP 1. {main}() /app/var/magerun:0 
PHP 2. N98\Magento\Application->run() /app/var/magerun:8 
PHP 3. N98\Magento\Application->init() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:307 
PHP 4. N98\Magento\Application->registerMagentoCoreCommands() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:388 
PHP 5. N98\Magento\Application->requireOnce() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:473 
PHP 6. N98\Magento\Application->N98\Magento\{closure}() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:537 
PHP 7. require_once() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:531 
PHP 8. require_once() /app/app/bootstrap.php:31 
PHP 9. include() /app/app/autoload.php:30 
PHP 10. ComposerAutoloaderInit08d293befa9981df91f94cf6c7b42eca::getLoader() /app/vendor/autoload.php:7 
PHP 11. composerRequire08d293befa9981df91f94cf6c7b42eca() /app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:61 
PHP 12. require() /app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:71 
PHP 13. class_exists() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php:12 
PHP 14. spl_autoload_call() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php:12 
PHP 15. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php:12 
PHP 16. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFile() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:321 
PHP 17. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFileWithExtension() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:351 
PHP 18. stream_resolve_include_path() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:429

Warning: stream_resolve_include_path(): Unable to find the wrapper "phar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 429

Call Stack: 
0.0002 384824 1. {main}() /app/var/magerun:0 
0.0385 2230624 2. N98\Magento\Application->run() /app/var/magerun:8 
0.0495 3188568 3. N98\Magento\Application->init() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:307 
0.1600 4145984 4. N98\Magento\Application->registerMagentoCoreCommands() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:388 
0.1600 4146032 5. N98\Magento\Application->requireOnce() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:473 
0.1600 4146352 6. N98\Magento\Application->N98\Magento\{closure}() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:537 
0.1601 4160248 7. require_once('/app/app/bootstrap.php') phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:531 
0.1602 4166336 8. require_once('/app/app/autoload.php') /app/app/bootstrap.php:31 
0.1603 4167728 9. include('/app/vendor/autoload.php') /app/app/autoload.php:30 
0.1604 4183496 10. ComposerAutoloaderInit08d293befa9981df91f94cf6c7b42eca::getLoader() /app/vendor/autoload.php:7 
0.2191 10630640 11. composerRequire08d293befa9981df91f94cf6c7b42eca() /app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:61 
0.2191 10632936 12. require('/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php') /app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:71 
0.2191 10632936 13. class_exists() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php:12 
0.2191 10633016 14. spl_autoload_call() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php:12 
0.2191 10633096 15. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php:12 
0.2191 10633096 16. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFile() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:321 
0.2192 10633096 17. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFileWithExtension() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:351 
0.2192 10633464 18. stream_resolve_include_path() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:429

PHP Warning: stream_resolve_include_path(): Unable to find the wrapper "phar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 429 
PHP Stack trace: 
PHP 1. {main}() /app/var/magerun:0 
PHP 2. N98\Magento\Application->run() /app/var/magerun:8 
PHP 3. N98\Magento\Application->init() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:307 
PHP 4. N98\Magento\Application->registerMagentoCoreCommands() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:388 
PHP 5. N98\Magento\Application->requireOnce() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:473 
PHP 6. N98\Magento\Application->N98\Magento\{closure}() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:537 
PHP 7. require_once() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:531 
PHP 8. require_once() /app/app/bootstrap.php:31 
PHP 9. include() /app/app/autoload.php:30 
PHP 10. ComposerAutoloaderInit08d293befa9981df91f94cf6c7b42eca::getLoader() /app/vendor/autoload.php:7 
PHP 11. composerRequire08d293befa9981df91f94cf6c7b42eca() /app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:61 
PHP 12. require() /app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:71 
PHP 13. class_exists() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php:12 
PHP 14. spl_autoload_call() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php:12 
PHP 15. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php:12 
PHP 16. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFile() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:321 
PHP 17. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFileWithExtension() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:351 
PHP 18. stream_resolve_include_path() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:429

Warning: stream_resolve_include_path(): Unable to find the wrapper "phar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 429

Call Stack: 
0.0002 384824 1. {main}() /app/var/magerun:0 
0.0385 2230624 2. N98\Magento\Application->run() /app/var/magerun:8 
0.0495 3188568 3. N98\Magento\Application->init() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:307 
0.1600 4145984 4. N98\Magento\Application->registerMagentoCoreCommands() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:388 
0.1600 4146032 5. N98\Magento\Application->requireOnce() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:473 
0.1600 4146352 6. N98\Magento\Application->N98\Magento\{closure}() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:537 
0.1601 4160248 7. require_once('/app/app/bootstrap.php') phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:531 
0.1602 4166336 8. require_once('/app/app/autoload.php') /app/app/bootstrap.php:31 
0.1603 4167728 9. include('/app/vendor/autoload.php') /app/app/autoload.php:30 
0.1604 4183496 10. ComposerAutoloaderInit08d293befa9981df91f94cf6c7b42eca::getLoader() /app/vendor/autoload.php:7 
0.2191 10630640 11. composerRequire08d293befa9981df91f94cf6c7b42eca() /app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:61 
0.2191 10632936 12. require('/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php') /app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:71 
0.2191 10632936 13. class_exists() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php:12 
0.2191 10633016 14. spl_autoload_call() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php:12 
0.2191 10633096 15. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php:12 
0.2191 10633096 16. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFile() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:321 
0.2192 10633096 17. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFileWithExtension() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:351 
0.2192 10633464 18. stream_resolve_include_path() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:429

PHP Warning: stream_resolve_include_path(): Unable to find the wrapper "phar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 429 
PHP Stack trace: 
PHP 1. {main}() /app/var/magerun:0 
PHP 2. N98\Magento\Application->run() /app/var/magerun:8 
PHP 3. N98\Magento\Application->init() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:307 
PHP 4. N98\Magento\Application->registerMagentoCoreCommands() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:388 
PHP 5. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:484 
PHP 6. Magento\Setup\Application->bootstrap() /app/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:71 
PHP 7. Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModules() /app/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Application.php:35 
PHP 8. Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php:129 
PHP 9. Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:248 
PHP 10. call_user_func:{/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490}() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490 
PHP 11. Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ServiceListener->onLoadModulesPost() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490 
PHP 12. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ServiceListener.php:207 
PHP 13. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:530 
PHP 14. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:597 
PHP 15. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:634 
PHP 16. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:1092 
PHP 17. call_user_func:{/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:934}() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:934 
PHP 18. Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory->createService() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:934 
PHP 19. Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory->__invoke() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/AbstractPluginManagerFactory.php:49 
PHP 20. Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory->configureHelpers() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:52 
PHP 21. class_exists() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:72 
PHP 22. spl_autoload_call() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:72 
PHP 23. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:72 
PHP 24. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFile() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:321 
PHP 25. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFileWithExtension() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:351 
PHP 26. stream_resolve_include_path() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:429

Warning: stream_resolve_include_path(): Unable to find the wrapper "phar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 429

Call Stack: 
0.0002 384824 1. {main}() /app/var/magerun:0 
0.0385 2230624 2. N98\Magento\Application->run() /app/var/magerun:8 
0.0495 3188568 3. N98\Magento\Application->init() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:307 
0.1600 4145984 4. N98\Magento\Application->registerMagentoCoreCommands() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:388 
0.2429 11891520 5. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:484 
0.2436 11951840 6. Magento\Setup\Application->bootstrap() /app/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:71 
0.2518 12792416 7. Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModules() /app/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Application.php:35 
0.2600 13073240 8. Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php:129 
0.2600 13073240 9. Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:248 
0.2601 13074928 10. call_user_func:{/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490}() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490 
0.2601 13074928 11. Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ServiceListener->onLoadModulesPost() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490 
0.2622 13166344 12. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ServiceListener.php:207 
0.2622 13167096 13. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:530 
0.2622 13167096 14. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:597 
0.2622 13167096 15. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:634 
0.2625 13197800 16. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:1092 
0.2625 13197880 17. call_user_func:{/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:934}() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:934 
0.2625 13197880 18. Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory->createService() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:934 
0.2625 13197880 19. Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory->__invoke() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/AbstractPluginManagerFactory.php:49 
0.2630 13278512 20. Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory->configureHelpers() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:52 
0.2675 13385280 21. class_exists() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:72 
0.2675 13385344 22. spl_autoload_call() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:72 
0.2675 13385408 23. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:72 
0.2675 13385408 24. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFile() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:321 
0.2675 13385408 25. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFileWithExtension() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:351 
0.2676 13385728 26. stream_resolve_include_path() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:429

PHP Warning: stream_resolve_include_path(): Unable to find the wrapper "phar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 429 
PHP Stack trace: 
PHP 1. {main}() /app/var/magerun:0 
PHP 2. N98\Magento\Application->run() /app/var/magerun:8 
PHP 3. N98\Magento\Application->init() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:307 
PHP 4. N98\Magento\Application->registerMagentoCoreCommands() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:388 
PHP 5. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:484 
PHP 6. Magento\Setup\Application->bootstrap() /app/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:71 
PHP 7. Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModules() /app/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Application.php:35 
PHP 8. Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php:129 
PHP 9. Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:248 
PHP 10. call_user_func:{/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490}() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490 
PHP 11. Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ServiceListener->onLoadModulesPost() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490 
PHP 12. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ServiceListener.php:207 
PHP 13. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:530 
PHP 14. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:597 
PHP 15. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:634 
PHP 16. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:1092 
PHP 17. call_user_func:{/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:934}() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:934 
PHP 18. Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory->createService() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:934 
PHP 19. Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory->__invoke() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/AbstractPluginManagerFactory.php:49 
PHP 20. Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory->configureHelpers() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:52 
PHP 21. class_exists() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:72 
PHP 22. spl_autoload_call() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:72 
PHP 23. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:72 
PHP 24. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFile() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:321 
PHP 25. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFileWithExtension() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:351 
PHP 26. stream_resolve_include_path() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:429

Warning: stream_resolve_include_path(): Unable to find the wrapper "phar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 429

Call Stack: 
0.0002 384824 1. {main}() /app/var/magerun:0 
0.0385 2230624 2. N98\Magento\Application->run() /app/var/magerun:8 
0.0495 3188568 3. N98\Magento\Application->init() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:307 
0.1600 4145984 4. N98\Magento\Application->registerMagentoCoreCommands() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:388 
0.2429 11891520 5. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct() phar:///app/var/magerun/src/N98/Magento/Application.php:484 
0.2436 11951840 6. Magento\Setup\Application->bootstrap() /app/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:71 
0.2518 12792416 7. Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModules() /app/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Application.php:35 
0.2600 13073240 8. Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php:129 
0.2600 13073240 9. Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:248 
0.2601 13074928 10. call_user_func:{/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490}() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490 
0.2601 13074928 11. Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ServiceListener->onLoadModulesPost() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490 
0.2622 13166344 12. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ServiceListener.php:207 
0.2622 13167096 13. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:530 
0.2622 13167096 14. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:597 
0.2622 13167096 15. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:634 
0.2625 13197800 16. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:1092 
0.2625 13197880 17. call_user_func:{/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:934}() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:934 
0.2625 13197880 18. Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory->createService() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:934 
0.2625 13197880 19. Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory->__invoke() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/AbstractPluginManagerFactory.php:49 
0.2630 13278512 20. Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory->configureHelpers() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:52 
0.2675 13385280 21. class_exists() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:72 
0.2675 13385344 22. spl_autoload_call() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:72 
0.2675 13385408 23. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /app/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php:72 
0.2675 13385408 24. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFile() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:321 
0.2675 13385408 25. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFileWithExtension() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:351 
0.2676 13385728 26. stream_resolve_include_path() phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:429


[Exception] 
Warning: file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper "phar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 384 

[Exception] 
Warning: stream_resolve_include_path(): Unable to find the wrapper "phar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in phar:///app/var/magerun/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 429
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case my issue was due to an old version of Magerun on the server. I updated and things worked fine.